# Simple C program not working because of no obvious reason

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I wanted to ask about the following C code, which is not working and i have no idea why. It does not enter in the if statement, but when I compile it in C++ with cin and cout instead of printf/scanf it works just fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

int sqrt(int x)
{
    if(x < 0) 
    {
        return printf("no negative numbers");
        return 0;
    } 
    else if(x == 0 || x == 1) 
    {
        return x;
    } 
    else
    {
        int lowerbound = 1, upperbound = x;
        int root = lowerbound + (upperbound - lowerbound)/2;

        while(root > x/root || root+1 <= x/(root+1))
        {
            if(root > x/root)
            {
                upperbound = root;
            } 
            else
            {
                lowerbound = root;
            }
            root = lowerbound + (upperbound - lowerbound)/2;
        }

        if(root*root==x)
        {
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    printf("start and an end:  ");
    scanf_s("%d%d", &start, &end);

    for (i = start; i < end; i++);
    {
        if(sqrt(i)>=0)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
            printf("---");
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "not working" - compilation error, run time error etc.

Comment: In what if statement doesn't the code enter?

Comment: `return printf("no negative numbers");
        return 0;` --> `fprintf(stderr, "no negative numbers");
        return -1;`

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to `#include <stdio.h>` to use `printf()` and `scanf_s()`
2. You `for` loop is erroneous. `for(i = start; i < end; i++);`
   So,

   ```
     if(sqrt(i)>=0)
     {
        printf("%d",i);
        printf("---");
     }
   ```

   will only be executed once and not `end-1` times if you are expecting it to. Remove the `;` after `for()`
3. `main` function is declared to be `void main()` and it in the end it does a `return`. Compiler must have thrown a warning here. Change that to `int main()` and `return` *something* which is a valid `int`.

Comment: Nothing changes when i include it. The program stops after entering ''start'' and ''end''

Answer (score 2):

Error is in this line

```
 for (i = start; i < end; i++);
                              ^   // remove `;` semicolon
```